# Count if contains yes using array formula for Google Form entries

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-forms, regex

I want to count every `yes` per submission of each Google Form, so the row.
Some of the responses have comments after the `yes` and it won't count those. This is the formula I am using:

```
={"Score"; ArrayFormula(if(len(A2:A), countif(if(C2:AP="yes", row(C2:C)), row(C2:C)),))}
```

I tried changing the `yes` to include asterisks around the `yes`, but that didn't work either. That made it not count any `yes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex formula

```
={"Score"; 
   INDEX(if(len(B2:B), 
             countif(if(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:G,"(?i)yes")="yes", row(D2:D)), row(D2:D)),))}
```

*(do adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

`(?i)` makes the regex **case insensitive**.
To turn the formula to case sensitive just omit it.

New functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly!!

Comment: *"Thank you very much! It worked perfectly!!"* **Please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you**. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Can I make this so that it doesn't count the empty cells?