# countif but not empty cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Can I make this formula not count empty cells?

```
={"Score"; INDEX(if(len(A2:A), countif(if(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:BE,"(?i)yes")="yes", row(C2:C)), row(C2:C)),))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following simple, still improved formula

```
={"Score"; 
   INDEX(IF(IF(LEN(B2:B), 
                COUNTIF(IF(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:G,"(?i)yes")="yes", ROW(D2:D)), ROW(D2:D)),)=0,"",
            IF(LEN(B2:B), 
                COUNTIF(IF(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:G,"(?i)yes")="yes", ROW(D2:D)), ROW(D2:D)),)))}
```

[image]

You will notice it is the same formula [given before](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/151700/117311) only this time we use an extra `IF` for when the result `=0`

Comment: So sorry for my late reply Kim. I totally missed your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I am being a real pain, but now when they answer no it won't count as zero. Is there any way to only get rid of the zero if the cells are blank? I know I may be asking for something impossible. I sure appreciate your help.